# Show particular row on selecting a checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, css, radio-button, show-hide

In my form I want when user selects first package radio button i.e. $400 there should appear a single dropdown list in Step2 i.e. Select String.

But when anyone select second package i.e. $550 there should appear two dropdown lists accepting two different inputs from the user respectively.

Similarly when third radio button selected I need three fields and in fourth I need four dropdown lists.

I have tried many things but its just not working out. Here is the code

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="orderform.php">
              <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
                  <td colspan="2" align="center"><strong class="style2">WILSON PACKAGE INFORMATION</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="right" valign="top"><strong class="style1">Step1 :<br>Select your Package</strong></td>
                  <td align="left"><p>
                    <label>
                      <input type="radio" name="package" value="$400 for 2 Wilson Rackets (msrp $623)" id="package_0">
                     <strong>$400 for 2 Wilson Rackets (msrp $623)</strong>
                     <br>6 sets of Wilson or Luxilon string.
                     <br>Tour 9pk bag.
                     <br>Pro Overgrip 12 pk.</label>
                    <br><br>
                    <label>
                      <input type="radio" name="package" value="$550 for 3 Wilson Rackets (msrp $949)" id="package_1">
                      <strong>$550 for 3 Wilson Rackets (msrp $949)</strong>
                      <br>12 sets of Wilson or Luxilon string.
                     <br>Tour 15pk bag.
                     <br>Pro Overgrip 12 pk.</label>
                    <br><br>
                    <label>
                      <input type="radio" name="package" value="$675 for 4 Wilson Rackets (msrp $1256)" id="package_2">
                      <strong>$675 for 4 Wilson Rackets (msrp $1256)</strong>
                      <br>18 sets of Wilson or Luxilon string.
                     <br>Tour 15pk bag.
                     <br>Pro Overgrip 12 pk.</label>
                    <br><br>
                    <label>
                      <input type="radio" name="package" value="$800 for 5 Wilson Rackets (msrp $1562)" id="package_3">
                      <strong>$800 for 5 Wilson Rackets (msrp $1562)</strong>
                      <br>24 sets of Wilson or Luxilon string.
                     <br>Tour 15pk bag.
                     <br>Pro Overgrip 12 pk.</label>
                    <br><br>
                  </p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="right" valign="top"><strong class="style1">Step 2:<br>Choose your String</strong><br>(Must order in multiples of 6)</td>
                  <td align="left"><label for="strings"></label>
                    <select name="strings" id="strings">
                      <option selected>Choose... </option>
                      <option value="Luxilon 4G Soft ">Luxilon 4G Soft </option>
                      <option value="Luxilon 4G 125">Luxilon 4G 125 </option>
                      <option value="Luxilon 4G Rough 125">Luxilon 4G Rough 125 </option>
                      <option value="Luxilon ALU Power 125 Silver">Luxilon ALU Power 125 Silver </option>
                      <option value="Luxilon ALU Power Rough 125 Silver">Luxilon ALU Power Rough 125 Silver </option>
                      <option value="Luxilon Savage 127 Black">Luxilon Savage 127 Black </option>
                      <option value="Wilson NXT 16 ">Wilson NXT 16 </option>
                      <option value="Wilson NXT 17">Wilson NXT 17 </option>
                      <option value="Wilson Revolve 16">Wilson Revolve 16 </option>
                      <option value="Wilson Revolve 17">Wilson Revolve 17 </option>
                      <option value="Wilson Sensation 16">Wilson Sensation 16 </option>
                      <option value="Wilson Sensation 17">Wilson Sensation 17 </option>
                  </select></td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: Are you looking for a jquery solution?

Comment: yes that will work. But I am not that good with it. 
But if you can help it will be great

Comment: Is it working correctly?

Comment: I was unable to apply that with my code. Can you help in that.

Comment: I asked more questions on my comment on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tutorial text from w3schools:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("p").hide();
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("p").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: I saw this while I was browsing for the answer but I was unable to apply this on my code .

Comment: #hide or #show are the elements ids that are clicked.  P is the element (use #p for specific id) to be shown or hidden.

Comment: And you have a CDN or preloaded minified Jquery?

Comment: Sorry but I am unable to attach it with my code :/ as i am not at all good with jquery.